# Fluentd is unable to write the logs to /fluentd/log Directory

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I have deployed a `fluentd` sidecar container with my application in a pod to collect logs from my app.

Here's my sidecar manifest `sidecar.yaml`:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fluentd
          image: fluent/fluentd
          ports:
          - containerPort: 24224
            protocol: TCP
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/td-agent/config.d
            name: configmap-sidecar-volume
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 101
            runAsGroup: 101
```

I used this manifest and patched it to my deployment using the following command:

```
kubectl patch deployment my-deployment --patch “$(cat sidecar.yaml)”
```

The deployment was successfully updated, however the my fluentd container can't seem to start and is throwing the following error:

```
2020-10-16 09:07:07 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
2020-10-16 09:07:08 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.11.2'
2020-10-16 09:07:08 +0000 [warn]: [output_docker1] 'time_format' specified without 'time_key', will be ignored
2020-10-16 09:07:08 +0000 [error]: config error file="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="out_file: `/fluentd/log/docker.20201016.log` is not writable"
```

This is my `fluent.conf` file:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  bind 127.0.0.1
  port 24224
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</source>
```

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

fluentd's UID default to `1000` unless it changed via env `FLUENT_UID`.

`/fluentd/log/docker.20201016.log is not writable` - error says that your user `101` doesn't have write permission to the log file. Change the security context to `1000` or set env `FLUENT_UID=101` to fix the issue.

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fluentd
          image: fluent/fluentd
          ports:
          - containerPort: 24224
            protocol: TCP
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/td-agent/config.d
            name: configmap-sidecar-volume
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1000
            runAsGroup: 1000
```

Related resources:

- [User id mapping between host and container](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-docker-image/pull/78)
- [No more access to mounted /fluentd/logs folder](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-docker-image/issues/173)

Comment: I tried both the approaches but it looks like the container runs for like few seconds and again goes to CrashLoopBackOff state.

Comment: @bakadevops still have the same error or something else?

Comment: It's weird but the error is gone after I changed the image from `fluent/fluentd` to `fluent/fluentd:v0.12.34`.

Comment: @bakadevops when you don't mention the image tag, it uses the latest version (`fluentd:latest`). And surprisingly it wasn't updated in last 2 years.

Comment: I'm aware. However, I thought the latest version would work.